# Not able to install fedena on 64 bit Win7

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, rake, fedena

I am able to create database with `rake db:create`.

I got error while `rake db:migrate` command executed.

```
C:\Fedena\fedena>rake db:migrate
(in C:/Fedena/fedena)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- rush

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My gem list is Below

```
actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
declarative_authorization (0.5.1
i18n (0.4.2)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.8.4)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
prawn (0.6.3)
prawn-core (0.6.3)
prawn-format (0.2.3)
prawn-layout (0.3.2)
prawn-security (0.1.1)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.8.7)
searchlogic (2.4.27)
tzinfo (0.3.38)
win32-open3 (0.3.2 x86-mingw32)
```

Comment: do `gem install rush` and then try?

Answer (score 1):

The other gems look okay, but you're missing rush. Run the following to install it:

```
gem install rush -v 0.6.8
```